# Python - Access and use specific object during runtime

Tags: python, oop

I am working on a bank account program where the user logs in with a four digit number (pin).

I want to find a way to access a specific object with all its attributes at runtime after the right pin has been entered.

```
class Konto(object):
    def __init__(self, account_holder, balance , pin):
        self.account_holder = account_holder
        self.balance = balance
        self.pin = pin
```

I have three different objects defined in a list

```
kontoList = []
kontoList.append(Konto("Person1", 143541, 1223)),
kontoList.append(Konto("Person2", 6230, 1234)), 
kontoList.append(Konto("Person3", 4578, 4321))
```

The last attribute is the Pin that is entered by the user. When the program checks the pin is '1234' for example it displays a menu where you can get the current balance, account holder etc. In this case it would be 6230 (balance) and Person2 (account holder). So here is some code:

```
pin = input("PIN: ")

for konto in kontoList:
    if konto.pin == pin:
        print("Valid PIN")
        continue
    else:
        print("not valid")
        break



while True:
    print("1: Withdrawal \n"
          "2: Deposit \n"
          "3: Transfer \n"
          "4: Current Balance \n"
          "5: Account Holder \n"
          "6: Quit \n")`

    choice = input("Your Choice: ")
```

Is there any way to access the specific object during runtime and then go on to work with it? I've looked up `getattr()` but it does not seem useful in this situation.

Comment: We don't know anything about `Konto`. Can you update your question with the definition? That way we might be able to figure out a better line of code than `if pin in kontoList:` which currently will always fail.

Comment: If you want to find objects by key (pin in this case), use a dictionary instead of a list. You can make the dictionary from the list like this: `d = {x.pin: x for x on kontolist}`

Comment: Presumably the account holder would need to enter their name or account number or something first. A PIN is a password, you can't use a password to identify someone, since PINs aren't globally unique (two people might share the same PIN).

Comment: @deceze When you are at an ATM your PIN is unique isnt it? That's why I the user enters the PIN instead of a name because a lot of people can have the same name. The PIN is basically the unique bank account number. I just named it PIN for several purposes.

Comment: At the ATM, you **insert your card** first, which identifies your account. Your PIN is then a *second factor* for security (to use the account, you need something *you have* (the card) and something *you know* (the PIN)).

Comment: If a 4-digit PIN was unique, a bank could only have a maximum of 8999 customers. And it would be pretty easy to guess other customers' PINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a list of pins, then check whether the pin you're checking is contained in that list:

```
kontoPinList = [konto.pin for konto in kontoList]
```

and then you would check whether your pin is in the kontoPinList with:

```
pin in kontoPinList
```

EDIT: If you want to keep working with the konto you do the following:

```
for konto in kontoList:
     if konto.pin == pin:
          #do something with the konto here
```

EDIT nr.2: If you wish to now call functions on the konto, such as account_holder(), you just do account_holder(konto) and that should work.

The reason my first response was to write a getPin() function is because while this will not solve your problem, it is a good idea to "protect" your variables by deciding how you want to return them. (it's more of a java thing than a python thing)

However, as you pointed out, it is a useless function if all you're interested in is simply returning konto.pin .

Comment: because it only returns the value of the given string doesn't it? But I would like to go on working with the object after that.

Comment: First of all thank you for the help. The big problem I have is that in the if clause I would like to call the functions e.g. account_holder() (in the menu above "5") on the object that matches the given Pin. Then the menu would be displayed again until "6" is entered. Sorry if my explanation sounds confusing but I could not find anything related to that. That is why I wrote that the getattr() method does not seem uesful in this case.

Comment: The if clause `pin in kontoPinList` does get skipped and it directly goes to the else clause but I don't know why? It should iterate through the PinList and therefore find the PIN right? Do you have an idea? I'm stuck again.

Comment: @RiseBlink there is a difference between "if pin in kontoList" and "for konto in kontoList: if pin == konto.pin".
The former means simply checks whether the pin is in the list, and returns true if it is, the latter checks if the konto you are using right now has a pin which matches "pin".

Comment: Well I edited my question to show you where I am stuck. Isn't there any possibility to have a 'pointer' to the matched object so that I can work with it in the later part of the program. In C++ you could do that but isn't there any Pythonic way?

Comment: I think "konto" is your pointer. In python all objects are simply referring to their memory address. Python allows you to simply use konto as your object.  If you want to have your balance, simply type konto.balance, if you want to have your account holder it would be konto.Person2 (I'm assuming that's how you named the variable that holds the name of the account holder).

Comment: Well when I do Konto.account_holder it only gives back the memory address. And when I do Konto.account_holder() it tells me something like 'parameter self unfilled' because I am not calling the function on an object but on the class Konto itself. But my problem right now is the if clause (above) that is not working correctly. Do you have any idea? I just want to display the menu when a valid pin is entered but no matter what i enter it says not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
kontos_with_pin = filter((lambda k: k.pin == pin), kontoList)
if len(kontos_with_pin) == 1:
   relevant_konto = kontos_with_pin[0]
   # Do something with relevant_konto
else:
    # handle case where there is no konto with that pin, or more than one, etc.
```